# What is the maximum number of active nodes possible in yugabyte db?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, yugabytedb

I am experimenting a theory on Yugabyte db and they have such a good performance metrics.
I want to know whether the Yugabyte Database can handle more than a million active nodes around the world and still have performance.

[Yugabyte website](https://www.yugabyte.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Happy to hear you are getting good perf! We have not tested the max number of nodes possible. We have stopped our testing at 100 nodes (these were 16 cores each). Theoretically, the design should allow any number of nodes so your scenario should work. However, in practice, there might be other implementation bottlenecks that can crop up - we would love to work through these with you. You may want to join our community Slack channel and ask for help if you hit any issue. Look forward to hearing how your tests go - I am curious as well!

(disclaimer: founder/cto @ yugabyte)

Comment: Thanks for replying, Looking forward to working with your team.